# Flutter Native Splash screen

Tags: flutter

i was wondering if its possible to remove the white square around the flutter icon. I am attaching the pubspec file, the results i get and the results i want to make everything more clear. i have done the process of flutter native splash screen but it doesnt seem to be changing anything.

the pubspec file:
[image: Pubspec.yaml]

what i get:
[image: the results i get]

and what i want:
[image: what i want]

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to turn the blue background to white?  If so, add `color` to your `android_12`:

```yaml
  android_12:
    # Splash screen background color.
    color: "#ffffff"
```